# Motion Tracking Tripod with Given Camera Settings

Tags: tracking

I want to track some footage from golf, as shown in the image. I have used FSpy to determine the position and focal length of the camera. Modelling two balls at the correct diameter in this space shows me that the perspective etc is perfectly fine.

The footage has a tripod mounted pan in it, moving up and to the right (towards the hole)

I can track the green etc and create the motion tracking file to my satisfaction, but when I "Solve Camera Motion" and "Set Tracking scene" it creates new geometry and new perspective etc which is different to my FSpy correct camera focal length and position.

I ONLY want to pan the camera I *have already created* with the tracking data.
How do I achieve this?

[image: fspy output]

Answer (score 2):

For a static camera the default camera solver will not work, you need to solve as **tripod**.

[image]

That will yield tracking points projected to a sphere only, but no real 3D information, but the camera move will be recreated.

Read:

[How can I get better results when doing camera motion tracking?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/42329/how-can-i-get-better-results-when-doing-camera-motion-tracking)