# How do I track the camera while knowing the specs of the camera?

Tags: camera, tracking

I'm currently tracking footage filmed on a Mavic Pro drone camera. I have all of the specs of the camera, but I'm not sure how to include it into my track. It's also an extremely easy track because the camera does nothing but a simple pan forward over a stadium.

Yet I'm running into all sorts of problems with the FOV and height and it's a bit frustrating. Here are the specs of the camera. How to I put this into Blender so it doesn't assume the info about the camera/change it after I click to solve camera motion?

Sensor – 1/2.3” (CMOS), Effective pixels:12.35 M (Total pixels:12.71 M)

Lens FOV: 78.8° 28 mm (35 mm format equivalent) f/2.2 with distortion of < 1.5% Focus from 0.5 m to ∞

ISO Range: 100-3200 (video)
100-1600 (photo)

Shutter Speed: 8s -1/8000s

Max Image Size: 4000 × 3000

EDIT: To the person who commented, I don't know how to reply but your thread did not help, the camera is not on a tripod, it's a flying drone shot that moves forward.

To make matters worse, my tracks have become less accurate now that I'm trying to do them again. My pixel solve errors are above 10, sometimes going above 90 despite the fact that the tracking markers are sitting directly on the points they're supposed to. I'm very confused.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Motion Tracking Tripod with Given Camera Settings](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/185189/motion-tracking-tripod-with-given-camera-settings)

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/42329/how-can-i-get-better-results-when-doing-camera-motion-tracking

Comment: I'm not sure if you can see this reply, but no. It doesn't help. I edited my post, please re-read it. Thank you for your help so far

Comment: Assumed it's just a pan (fixed location) so you'd have to use the tripod option. Sorry, apparently misread. Anyway, each shot is different and and it's hard to guess what your issue is. Suggest upload a few seconds of the footage so we can have a look.

Comment: I was wrong, it's not a pan. The camera is flying. I mistook a pan for a movement. I'll upload a video soon

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=f9q1z8Pwjh0